# SQL Average or MAX of one column in query for pivot table

Tags: sql, sum, max, pivot-table

I have a query that shows everytime an employee clocks in or out at a customer site.  I've already worked out the math for calculating their hours for each visit to a site.  Is it possible to just get the average or max value of the invoice amount column for CompanyA?

I'm trying to use this data in a pivot table, but it will SUM the Invoice Amount for that customer showing '690.0000' and then it totals in the "Grand Total".  This makes the math wrong for the grand total.  I want it to just account for the one value of 345.00.  The InvoiceAmount is always the same no matter how many times they clocked in and out there.

Is there something I can do in my query before it's pulled into the pivot table?

| ProjectName | InvoiceAmount | HoursPerRow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CompanyA | 345.00 | 19 |
| CompanyA | 345.00 | 2 |

```
declare @current_cst datetimeoffset;
set @current_cst = (SELECT getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time')

SELECT        
    dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.EmployeeID, 
    dbo.Employees.FirstName + ' ' + dbo.Employees.LastName AS EmployeeFullName, 
    dbo.Projects.ProjectName, 
    MAX (dbo.WorkOrderProjects.InvoiceAmount) AS InvoiceAmount,
    dbo.WorkOrders.WorkOrderID, 
    AVG (dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.Wage) AS Wage,
    convert(datetime,switchoffset(convert(datetimeoffset, dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.ClockIn),datename(tzoffset,@current_cst))) AS ClockIn,
    convert(datetime,switchoffset(convert(datetimeoffset, dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.ClockOut),datename(tzoffset,@current_cst))) AS ClockOut,
    CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(mi, ClockIn, ClockOut) / 60) as Hrs_Difference,
    CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(mi, ClockIn, ClockOut) % 60) as Mins_Difference,
    DATEDIFF(second, dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.ClockIn, dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.ClockOut) / 3600.0 as HoursPerRow
             
                


FROM                    
    dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker INNER JOIN
    dbo.WorkOrders ON dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.WorkOrderID = dbo.WorkOrders.WorkOrderID INNER JOIN
    dbo.WorkOrderProjects ON dbo.WorkOrders.WorkOrderProjectID = dbo.WorkOrderProjects.WorkOrderProjectID INNER JOIN
    dbo.Employees ON dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.EmployeeID = dbo.Employees.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
    dbo.Projects ON dbo.WorkOrderProjects.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ProjectID
    where dbo.WorkOrderProjects.IsPaid = 'True'

    group by 
            dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.EmployeeID, 
            dbo.Employees.FirstName, 
            dbo.Employees.LastName,
            dbo.WorkOrderProjects.InvoiceAmount,
            dbo.Projects.ProjectName,
            dbo.WorkOrders.WorkOrderID, 
            dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.Wage,
            WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.ClockIn,
            dbo.WorkOrderEmployeeTimeTracker.ClockOut
    order by 1,2,3
```

I only want the Invoice Amount once when there is a duplicate.  I still need the other information from each row though, as employees have different clock times when they have clocked in and out more than once for the same project.

UPDATE:  It would seem that covertion on the clockin and clockout were throwing everything off.  Removing them solved everything.  I Will have to find a way to convert these times to Central Standard Time.

If anyone has proper ideas on that, please let me know.

Comment: Could you provide expected result from your sample data? not clear from your question.

Comment: I have added the query to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is aggregate functions that will help like MAX function
you can write

```
 SELECT MAX(InvoiceAmount) FROM TableName
```

and there is other functions like AVG and can be used on on column

Comment: I've tried MAX (WorkOrderProjects.InvoiceAmount) AS InvoiceAmount It doesn't change anything when running the query.

Comment: @Aakburns mind sharing your query?

Comment: I have added the query to the question.